# Spring REST templates - difference between put() and exchange()

Tags: spring, rest

This is a test case I was writing for `update` calls to database:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateList() {
    //
    //... Some variables
    //
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    String requestBody = "{\"id\":\"" + givenId + "\",\"listName\":\"" + listName + "\",\"owner\":\"" + owner + "\"}";

    HttpEntity <String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);

    // Call to update
    ResponseEntity <TaskListResponse> list = template.exchange(REQUEST_URL + "/list/update/{id}", HttpMethod.PUT, entity, TaskListResponse.class, params);
}
```

Here `params` is a name-value HashMap for the REST URL.

When I wanted to update a `list` type, since `RestTemplate.put()` doesn't have a return type, I used HTTP requests.
A call with `template.put` would look like this:

```
   template.put(REQUEST_URL + "/list/update/{id}", request, params);
```

- But I don't know the difference between the two types of calls. Could someone explain it to me in reference to the above code? How can `template.exchange` return a value, if it's a `PUT` request?
- What I'm looking for is that since I used `template.post/get/delete` for `create()`, `search()` and `delete()`, should I use `.put()` for `update()` as well, even though I won't get a response?

Comment: Naturally the output of the test is exactly the same for both calls to `System.out.println()`.

Comment: Generally use GET for search, POST for create and PUT for update.  If you're updating you don't need a return type.

Comment: @EssexBoy I know that generally we don't, but what if we wanted a response from the database as to what the values are after they get updated, this would what we'd be doing.

Comment: For clarification, I want the difference in the working of the two calls, not their nature(GET, PUT,... I already know that).

Comment: In the end they are the same `put` is simpler then `exchange` and depending on what you need to post (or convert) use one or the other. The `exchange` method simply returns the response, which would be generally just a status code, or the result of a redirect or....